# Change directory address from terminal by python

Tags: python, linux

I was wondering if it is possible to change a part of directory address by user input? For example in Linux command line we can use this command:

```
read -p "Enter your interface : " case
grep "ACC" $case/PATH.dat >> $case/PATH_ACC.dat
python acctraj.py >> $case/ENERGIES_ACC.dat
```

Is there anything similar in Python? Here is a code in Python, can I import the "INTERFACE" value from the keyboard?

```
import numpy as np

INTERFACE = input('Enter your interface: ')
def read_path(inputfile="/INTERFACE/PATH_ACC.dat"):
        with open(inputfile, "r") as fileh:
                for lines in fileh:
                        linesplit = lines.split()
                        yield linesplit[0:3]
acc = [idx for idx in read_path()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement this using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and by passing the user input as an argument to the function:

```
import numpy as np

def read_path(interface):
    inputfile = "/{0}/PATH_ACC.dat".format(interface)
    with open(inputfile, "r") as fileh:
        for lines in fileh:
            linesplit = lines.split()
            yield linesplit[0:3]

interface = input('Enter your interface: ')
acc = [idx for idx in read_path(interface)]
```